# How to use Ajax & jQuery to change data order retrieved at table in Blade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I have retrieved the list of `users` at a table in Blade:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="contentDiv">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>User Status</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
</table>
```

And this is my Controller method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::query();

        if(request('desc') == 1){
             $users->orderBy('id','DESC');
        }else{
             $users->orderBy('id','ASC');
        }

        $users = $users->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('admin.users.all', compact('users'));
    }
```

Then I tried adding a select option that can change the table order:

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="dropdown-list">
     <option value="asc" selected="selected">Ascending</option>
     <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

So for example if user clicks on `Descending` option, an ajax request must change the table order from `asc` to `desc`.

And here is my try on Ajax:

```
   $("#dropdown-list").on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

        if(val == "desc") {
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/admin/users?desc=1',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    val: val,
                },
                jsonType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#contentDiv tr").remove();
                    // populate new data and append to table
                }
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/admin/users',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    val: val,
                },
                jsonType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#contentDiv tr").remove();
                    // populate new data and append to table
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So I try removing the entire table contents and after that I should populate the new data (`$users`) and append them to table.

How can I do that?

### Update #1 on Martin Amu's answer

I tried everything he says but when I test, I get this error:

> Undefined variable: orderby

Which is referring to this line:

`$data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', $orderby)->paginate(20);`

I also tried `$data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', $orderby)->get();` but still shows the same error.

Meaning that the `if..else` conditions on `OrderBy` method does not run, because I also tested this but none of the conditions ran and skipped to the next line:

```
        if($request->has('order_by') && $request->order_by == "asc")
        {
            dd(1);
        } elseif($request->has('order_by') && $request->order_by == "desc")
        {
            dd(2);
        }
```

After that I tried making the query manually like this:

```
$data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

And it successfully pushes the data into the table but some of the fields are set to **Undefined** somehow.

Another thing is that, I need to load the the table when the page loads at first time. But now it is empty and I have to make changes to that select option in order to push data into the table.

Comment: There is a typo by me. Now corrected but i will work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="contentDiv">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>User Status</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
</table>

<table class="table table-hover" id="ajaxView" style="display:none">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>User Status</th>
      </tr>
     
      <tr id="user-list">
          
      </tr>
      
</table>


<select class="form-control select2" id="dropdown-list" name="dropdown-list">
     <option value="asc" selected="selected">Ascending</option>
     <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

**JS in view:**

```
<script>
$("#dropdown-list").on('change', function(){
         var orderBy = document.getElementById("dropdown-list").value;
            $('#contentDiv').hide();
            $('#ajaxView').show();
            $("#user-list").html('');

            if(orderBy == 'asc')
            {
            var orderBy = 1;
            } else if(orderBy == 'desc')
            {
            var orderBy = 2;
            }

            $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url('/api/orderby-users')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        order_by: orderBy,
                        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',                 
                    success: function (result) {                        
                        $.each(result.orderby, function (key, value) {                                                         
                          $("#user-list").append('<td>' + value.id + '</td> <td>' + value.name + '</td> <td>' + value.email + '</td> <td>' + value.status + '</td>');
                        });                                            
                     }
                 });
              });        
</script>
```

**Controllers:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::query();

        $users = $users->latest()->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(20);

        return view('admin.users.all', compact('users'));
    }

public function OrderBy(Request $request)
{
 if($request->order_by == 1)
 {
  $data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

 } elseif($request->order_by == 2)
 {
  $data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
 }
 
 return response()->json($data);
}
```

**Route:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\YOURController;
Route::post('api/orderby-users', [YOURController::class, 'OrderBy']);
```

Comment: Great attempt, but I get **`Undefined variable: orderby`** in the Controller method which is referring to this line of `OrderBy` method: `$data['orderby'] = User::orderBy('id', $orderby)->paginate(20);`

Comment: change paginate to get();

Comment: And there was a typo. I edited my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks for taking time & effort, I have added an **UPDATE #1** about your answer, please check it out...

Comment: Check it now this is work fine for me.

Comment: My answer is correct please accept it because in the future some visitors might need this solution.

Comment: Yes your answer is surely correct but the only problem is that when you change the select option order order one time, it will appends the data correctly to the table but when you change it once again it appends the data one more time TO THE EXISTING DATA which is not correct.

Comment: In fact it should empty the results and again fills it when changing the select option. So how to do this?

Comment: Also I added changed it to this: `$("#user-list").append('<tr>...</tr>');`  and added `user-list` to `<tbody>` of the table

Comment: Please add $("#user-list").html('');
after  $('#ajaxView').show();

Comment: Would you take a look at this question which is also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73201845/how-to-use-laravel-codes-as-ajax-response

Comment: Do you want implement all operation in a bootstrap pop up modal? I have an idea for that.